# How do we make an inactive field mandatory in EPICOR?

Tags: epicor10

The Primary Bin field is disabled (Grayed out) by default, when we create a new part in Part Maintenance. I need to prevent a user to save a part if he did not enter a primary bin number. Is that possible?

Note: I tried BPM but it did not work. I created a method directive and I put this Condition: "ttPartWhse.PrimBinNum filed of the changed row is equal to the null"

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Zimo. In my understanding, there are necessary steps to creating the Part all the way through to the Primary Bin. Primary Bin is data that lives under the Site / Warehouse for the Part record. For instance, Part Maintenance, do New Part - but try to do new Site immediately and observe this error:

> Part is required. Description is required. Class is required.

So, you can see that the system expects a certain series of events to occur here.

Now, what you could do, just generally speaking here, is to use the BPM data directive to "monitor" the part warehouse additions such that new part site warehouse data coming in would need the Primary Bin to not be Null. So you would need to identify the proper table where this data lives ( like PartWhse ) and then implement the BPM against new data going in there.

Alternatively, you may desire to do something with reports, a BAQ, or perhaps an updateable BAQ or Dashboard that lets users find those problems easily, and correct them.